# QT how to change application window z index

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, uiview, qml

I was trying to get native `iOS` player as a custom `QML` component and managed to do it thanks to [this](https://github.com/seyedmmousavi/Native-UITextView-on-Qt-KDAB). However I'm facing a problem with z order of the component.

Component constructor:

```
MyVideoView::MyVideoView(QQuickItem *parent /*= 0*/)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
    , m_view(0)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(windowChanged(QQuickWindow*)), this, SLOT(onWindowChanged(QQuickWindow*)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(visibleChanged()), this, SLOT(onVisibleChanged()));
}
```

onWindowChanged implementation:

```
void MyVideoView::onWindowChanged(QQuickWindow* window)
{
    if(!m_view) {
    }
    if (window != 0) {

        UIView *parentView = reinterpret_cast<UIView *>(window->winId());

                AVPlayer *_player;
                AVURLAsset *_asset;
                AVPlayerItem *_playerItem;
                AVPlayerLayer *m_playerLayer;

                _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
                NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
                _asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:baseURL];
                _playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: _asset];
                [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
                m_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];

                m_playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height());

                [parentView.layer addSublayer:m_playerLayer ];

                [_player play];


    } else {
        [m_view removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Whit this I can use the component in my application which is an `ApplicationWindow`, but the issue is, the component is always on top, covering the whole application even if I set:

```
MyVideoView {
    z:-3
    width: 300
    height: 200
    x:20
    y:300
}
```

Or put z of another component to e.g. `300`.
I assume it's because of [QQuickWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html) or caused by `UIView`.
Edit: `MyVideoView` is placed inside an `Item` component

What I would want to achieve is to:

- either make it possible to set the components z order
- or get the component "behind" the application (creating transparent part on my app so the video is visible, not the best solution but I'm running out of options)

Is there any way to achieve one of those, or can it be done if the component is something else besides a `QQuickItem`, since the only part I actually need is the player layer, as I'll create a custom playback control interface?

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is not possible.
If I understand right the `window->winId()` should be the actual application window itself, so I tried to bring a 3rd UIView which would hold the application "window->winId()" superview and `m_playerLayer` (which I put inside another UIView) just so that I could change their display order using `bringSubviewToFront` and `sendSubviewToBack`.
But no matter what I try the player component is always on top, like it's completely separated from the whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint from Tor, I managed to get it to work. 
First I created another `UIView` to place `m_playerLayer` inside it.

and then got the player behind:

```
[playerView.layer addSublayer:m_playerLayer];
[parentView.window addSubview: playerView];
[parentView.window sendSubviewToBack: playerView];
parentView.opaque = NO;
```

It's important to point out that without `parentView.opaque = NO` the application would still have a background even with `ApplicationWindow` `color: "transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

`QQuickWindow` is a `UIView`. The individual QML items are not, so you can't place another `UIView`(or its layer) "inside" a QML application unless you structure the application as a top level `QQuickWindow` with additional child `QQuickWindow` and then sandwich the video layer between those Qt Quick windows (`QWindows`).